# Unity Loading Scene with player data

Tags: unity

I have a empty scene, which loads another scene which is loading player data onStart. When the empty scene transition to the loading player scene. A loading bar is created on the empty scene and it shows me 100% and stuck for couple seconds. I've used Debug.Log and i only see is 0-9. Nothing between like 0.20, 0.40 and etc...

I can see on the hierarchy that loading player data scene, is loading while it's stuck on the 100%

Update:
I've made some futher tests, it seems my problem is that loading player data through awake or start. Does not get executed while loading a scene async. How can i load the player data aswell with the progress bar. Since the player data is stored as a file. This is purely because when i open my game, after the unity splash logo. It's a black screen, due to it's loading the player data.

```
    private IEnumerator LoadSceneProgress(Scene scene)
    {
        AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(Tools.TitleCase(scene.ToString()));
        while (!operation.isDone)
        {
            float progress = Mathf.Clamp01(operation.progress / .9f);
            loadingSlider.value = progress;
            loadingSliderText.text = progress * 100 + "%";
            Debug.Log(operation.progress);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

public static bool LoadPlayer(PlayerObject player)
{
    SaveData loadData = LoadFile();
    player.Level = loadData.Level;

    // Load items inventory
    List<Item> itemList = loadData.ItemsInventory;
    if (itemList != null)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < itemList.Count; a++)
        {
            Item item = itemList[a];
            Item newItem = player.GetInventory.AddItem(new Item(item.Id, item.Amount));
        }
    }
}

private static SaveData LoadFile()
{
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.dat";
    SaveData data = null;
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        data = ZeroFormatterSerializer.Deserialize<SaveData>(fileStream);
    }

    return data;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you should move the code that loads the player data to the function that loads the new scene. Kick off both the scene load and the save data load/deserialization asynchronously, and display the minimum progress of either operation. Once both operations are done, allow the game to transition to your second scene.

Comment: How can i load the data asynchronously?

Comment: [What does your research tell you](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o)?

Comment: Oh i see, thanks man. I'll try it out

Comment: If you find a working solution before another user provides one, please feel free to post it as an Answer below. :)

Comment: I'll do that, since i think i'm not the only one who need a solution for this :)